# How to redirect user from mobile browser to Apps (android & ios)

Tags: javascript, android, html, reactjs, web

I'm trying to find out those dialog info for Web Apps if opened in mobile browser, that has button to open by Android/IOS Apps.

Like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsYbW.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBgHm.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQFn7.png)

I'm trying to figure out is this created by the Web Apps? or by the mobile apps?
And for the button to open the app link, I've been doing reserach is it called universal link?

Any info would be appreciated, I'm kinda lost in this one

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you have two different options. I will explain the options and how to handle them in the app.

The first option is ['Smart App Banners'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners) which was introduced in iOS 7. This uses meta tags to tell the browser, which app is linked to the website.

The second option is using ['universal links'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content?language=swift). This will redirect to the specific without letting the user interact with such a banner. In some cases, this is preferable but differs on a case-to-case base.

With both of the above solutions, you will have the option to redirect to a specific section in the app.